# Intersection of two unions of families of sets proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was asked to proof this.
"Given two families of sets $\{X_i\}_{i \in I},\ \{Y_j\}_{j \in J}$  in some universe set E.

Prove that $$\left(\bigcup_{i \in I} X_i\right) \cap \left(\bigcup_{j \in J} Y_j\right) = \bigcup_{(i,j) \in I \times J} (X_i \cap Y_j)$$"

I tried some simple case. I take two elements of the first family $X_a\ \text{and} \ X_b$ and two elements from the other family $Y_c\ \text{and} \ Y_d$ then I do the intersection resulting in $(X_a \cap Y_c) \cup (X_a \cap Y_d) \cup (X_b \cap Y_c) \cup (X_b \cap Y_d)$, as expected. However, I dont know how to generalize this result.

Comment: Try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction

Comment: @KB Induction is of no help here since $I$ and $J$ are not assumed finite.

Comment: As long as I & J are countable, Induction works. To begin, for size $j=1$, prove by induction for all $i \in I$. Then assume true for size $j=j'$, and for size $j=j'+1$ - prove by induction for all $i \in I$. That's how double induction works. Although solution given below is easier.

Comment: As long as you accept that all sets can be well ordered, you _could_ use transfinite induction on the index sets.  However, that is massively overkill.  The easy way to show two sets are equal is to show they are subsets of each other, like in @Nirai 's answer

Comment: I think about using induction, but in my course induction, natural numbers, countable sets and finite sets comes after this topic. So, i think this was thought to be done without that. However thanks for your replies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x \in \left(\bigcup_{i \in I}X_i\right) \cap \left(\bigcup_{j \in J}Y_j\right)$. Then $x \in \left(\bigcup_{i \in I}X_i\right)$ and $x \in \left(\bigcup_{j \in J}Y_j\right)$. This implies there exist $m \in I$ and $n \in J$ such that $x \in X_m$ and $x \in Y_n$. This is the same as saying $x\in X_m \cap Y_n$, which implies $x \in \bigcup_{(i, j) \in I\times J} (X_i \cap Y_j)$. Hence, we have $\left(\bigcup_{i \in I}X_i\right) \cap \left(\bigcup_{j \in J}Y_j\right) \subset \bigcup_{(i, j) \in I\times J} (X_i \cap Y_j)$. Can you do the other direction?

In fact, all of the implications above are also equivalences, so there is not much work left. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks very much, can i apply that on the other case? i mean $\left(\bigcap_{i \in I} X_i\right) \cup \left(\bigcap_{j \in J} Y_j \right) = \bigcap_{(i,j) \in I \times J} (X_i \cup Y_j)$

Comment: I have a question, here u use that if $A \subset B \land C \subset D \Rightarrow A \cap C \subset B \cap D$ ?

Comment: @Nicolas I don't use that. At each step I simply use the definitions of union and intersection. For the other case, you simply need to show that the RHS of the equation you want to prove is a subset of the LHS. Once you have proven that, you know that the LHS is a subset of the RHS and the RHS is a subset of the LHS, which means they are equal. Hope that clears it up.

Comment: @Nicolas Did that answer your question?